# Cannot get list of data from cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am wanting to get the list of data from the cloud firestore. I have setup everything. With the following code, i am just able to get one data instead of all the list. And I am getting the following error :
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

```
 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      static const routeName = 'homePage';
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      late String id;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Latest"),
             backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("latest").orderBy('number',descending: true).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return !snapshot.hasData
                  ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                  : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  return  Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    fit: StackFit.loose,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        child: Container(
                            height: 200,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: Card(
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          data['name'],
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.indigo,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                                                                                        ])),
                            )),
                        onTap: () {
                                         },
                      )
                    ],
                    //   ),
                  );
    
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check the document fields name and also make sure all the fields exist in all documents.

Comment: Thanks. There was unintentional space in the field name.